# How to check dynamic text field is available in previous page

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have code like this in `add.php`

```
function rowInsertion() {
     var table = document.getElementById("bannerTable");
     var row = table.insertRow(5);
     var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
     var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
     cell1.innerHTML = "IMAGE:";
     cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='file' name='img_name' id='img_name'  />";
     var x = document.getElementById("bannerTable").rows.length;
}

function rowDeletion() {
     var x = document.getElementById("bannerTable").rows.length;
     if (x >= 12) {     
           document.getElementById("bannerTable").deleteRow(5);         
     }
}
```

and another code in another page get.php to get input of text like this

```
$img_name = $_POST['img_name'];
```

but i am getting error for undefined index 'img_name' when row isn't available. How to apply a check in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are submitting the data via `$_POST`, Just check if the index `img_name` is set, and if `true` then proceed.

```
if(isset($_POST['img_name'])){
  $img_name = $_POST['img_name']; // setting the value to the input
} else {
  $img_name = ''; // setting the value to blank, to prevent undefined error.
}
```

Note as of `php 7.x.x` theres this (*long awaited*) [Null Coalesce Operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) That does exact this but in a single line.

```
$img_name = $_POST['img_name'] ?? ''; // TheMoreYouKnow :)
```

Comment: But how to check index img_name exist rather than its value

Comment: In case of an associative array like `$_POST`, the `isset()` function actually checks if the "key" is set (exists) and returns true/false based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for existing post data using

```
if ( isset( $_POST['img_name'] ) )
    $img_name = $_POST['img_name'];
```

Comment: i tried this on get.php page                                                                       if (isset( $_POST['img_name'])){
  $img_name = $_POST['img_name'];
  echo "image name = ".$img_name.'<br>';
 }
 else
 {
  echo "no image".'<br>'; 
 }

Comment: but its still printing no image weather i insert row or not

Comment: That means that $_POST['img_name'] is probably never being set. Do you actually post to your php script? Have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp)